# Find all returning empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, beautifulsoup

I am using the code below to extract from the HTML below. Not sure what I am doing wrong but code is returning an empty list. I am trying to extract the "Red Hat" text.

```
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
page_names = page.find_all('span', class_='keyword')
```

HTML:

```
<span class="keyword">Red Hat</span>
```

Comment: That can't be the code you are using, because it's a syntax error to use "class" except as a keyword.

Comment: Some how missed the underscore when typing. Edited code to be consistent with what I have been running.

Comment: Use `page.select_one('.keyword').text`

Answer (score 0):

To extract text we need to use .getText() try the code below  it should work

```
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
for x in page.find_all('span', class_='keyword'):
    print(x.getText())
```